# SQLite does not support this migration operation ('AlterColumnOperation')

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

This is my DbContext:

```
using DatingApp.API.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DatingApp.API.Data
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options){ }

        public DbSet<Value> Values { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my generated file migrations:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace DatingApp.API.Migrations
{
    public partial class ExtendedUserClass : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "Username",
                table: "User",
                nullable: true,
                oldClrType: typeof(int));

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "City",
                table: "User",
                nullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "Country",
                table: "User",
                nullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
                name: "Created",
                table: "User",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
                name: "DateOfBirth",
                table: "User",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "Gender",
                table: "User",
                nullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "Interests",
                table: "User",
                nullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "Introduction",
                table: "User",
                nullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "KnownAs",
                table: "User",
                nullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
                name: "LastActive",
                table: "User",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "LookingFor",
                table: "User",
                nullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Photos",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                    Url = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Description = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    DateAdded = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    IsMain = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    UserId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Photos", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Photos_User_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "User",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Photos_UserId",
                table: "Photos",
                column: "UserId");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Photos");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "City",
                table: "User");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "Country",
                table: "User");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "Created",
                table: "User");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "DateOfBirth",
                table: "User");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "Gender",
                table: "User");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "Interests",
                table: "User");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "Introduction",
                table: "User");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "KnownAs",
                table: "User");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "LastActive",
                table: "User");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "LookingFor",
                table: "User");

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
                name: "Username",
                table: "User",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldNullable: true);
        }
    }
}
```

Tries to delete database migration
I update, add the migration from scratch, try to execute the dotnet ef database update command and get the message:

```
SQLite does not support this migration operation ('AlterColumnOperation'). For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723262.
```

I don't know exactly what to do to add the migration in SQL lite, which is why the problem arises.

How can I change a column? Because that's probably what it is.

Comment: basically: you change the column. SQLite doesn't support it. you could instead write your own migration that creates a completely _new_ table, then `SELECT INTO` that table. (those migration problems actually are a reason i'm looking for an alternative to SQLite)

Comment: (forgot the "can't" before "change", but realised it too late to edit)

Comment: Franz thanks for the answer but I am adding migration manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the database and all existing migrations and run again `add-migration InitialCreate` which will create a new migration starting from scratch so there won't be any columns to alter.

Comment: YStroli your solution helped

Comment: best solutions... add-migrations before Update-Database

Comment: it works, but isn't a good solution as it removes the entire database and all test data is permanently gone.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute this commands:

```
dotnet ef migrations remove 
dotnet ef migrations add initialCommit
dotnet ef database update
```

But the best solutions was when I commented out AlterColumn lines on the Migration class file, it compiled successfully, and created my database as well

But taught me a lesson: **no to use code-first with SQLite**.